# Querying other database using whererIn() and leftJoin() in the same query

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

To get the posts from another database corresponding to the id of the $ids array I use, for example, the following query (it works fine):

```
 $ids = [1, 2, 4, 7];

 $data = DB::connection('mysqlDatabase2')
            ->table('posts')
            ->whereIn('id_post', $ids)
            ->get();
```

Post has many comments.

**The problem to solve** is to also get the comments related to each post.

I tried with the following query, which returns two problems:

1- posts are returned duplicated;

2- return just one comment per post instead of an array with all related comments

```
$ids = [1, 2, 4, 7];

$data = DB::connection('mysqlDatabase2')
            ->table('posts')
            ->whereIn('posts.id_post', $ids)
            ->leftJoin('comments', 'post.id_post', '=', 'comments.id_post')
            ->get();
```

**Edited**:

The following is happening: if a post has three related comments, it returns the same post three times, each with one of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Dont Use Joins. You can use the Eloquent ORM

In Your Model Post.php file:

```
//If you want All comments related to posts
public function comments(){
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'id_post')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

//If you want Single latest comment related to posts
public function latestComment(){
return $this->hasOne(Comment::class, 'id_post')->latest('created_at');
}
```

Now, in your controller you can use this like:

```
$data = Post::with('latestComment')->get();
```

Or

```
$data = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

Comment: thanks for helping. Your solution is ideal to use with model and the corresponding APP Database. The problem is that the query is made to the database of another application, being necessary to use DB connection. It seems impractical to use eloquent.

Comment: why Eloquent seems impractical. Laravel strongly supports and provides you the Eloquent ORM.

Comment: If you working in core php then db connection name is required to provide

Comment: To better exemplify, APP A has Post and Comment Models and Database A.
In APP B, I need to get the Post and related comments from APP A; that is, first of all, I need to access Database A, using multiple database connections. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections
If you see any way to connect with Database A and with APP A models to use eloquent, that would help.

Comment: Although it may not be ideal (in the real case it involves a lot of models), I opted for the pragmatic solution of replicating all the necessary models from APP A to APP B, with the difference that in APP B, each model has added protected $connection = 'mysqlDatabase2 '. In this way, the use of eloquent is feasible.